# difference between 0.0.0.0 and * network in ss output

Tags: linux, networking, routing

The `ss` command seems to distinguish between `*` and `0.0.0.0`. While the listing of ssh with `0.0.0.0:22` and `[::]:22` is clear, `*:7946` and `*:80` is not quite as much.

```
$ ss -ntl
State    Recv-Q   Send-Q     Local Address:Port     Peer Address:Port  
LISTEN   0        128              0.0.0.0:22            0.0.0.0:*     
LISTEN   0        128                    *:7946                *:*     
LISTEN   0        128                    *:80                  *:*     
LISTEN   0        128                 [::]:22               [::]:*
```

Why isn't it `0.0.0.0:7946` and `0.0.0.0:80`? What's the difference here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference lies inside the address family:

`0.0.0.0:22` : This is a listen socket which accepts connections on any interface, port 22 for IPv4 connections only.

`[::]:22` : Same here, but for IPv6 connections.

```
LISTEN   0        128                    *:80                  *:*
```

And this is a listen sockets which accepts IPv4 as well as IPv6 connection requests.

Comment: So 0.0.0.0:22 and [::]:22 are two sockets, one for each address family. 
*:80 is one socket that listens for both? Isn't that still two sockets on the network stack?

Comment: no... as far as I know, the linux socket call accepts ```AF_UNSPEC``` as address family... besides, programms like ss and netstat lists the socket one by one; you would see the socket twice if it were two sockets on the network stack.

Comment: Awesome. I knew it must have been something simple. Was hard to search for because of the "*" :) Thanks!

Comment: I have to apologize, my comment about the ```AF_UNSPEC``` was incorrect - the correct way to open an socket which supports both address family is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1618240/how-to-support-both-ipv4-and-ipv6-connections

Comment: You can ask ss to be more verbose about it: `ss -ntl -e` will add amont other information `v6only:0`for sockets listening to both and `v6only:1` for pure ipv6 (you can use `socat`'s `ipv6only=1` option to test).